# Let $g(x),h(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $h(x)$ is monic. If $h(x)$ divides $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ then $h(x)$ divides $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

> **Question**: Let $g(x),h(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $h(x)$ is monic. If $h(x)$ divides $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ then $h(x)$ divides $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

I know that, as $h(x)$ divides $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ hence $$g(x)=h(x)q(x)\qquad (*)$$ for some $q(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Let $b$ be lcm of denominators of coefficients of $q(x)$ then from above we have, $bh(x)=g(x)(bq(x))=g(x)q_1(x)$ for some $q_1(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. As given that $h(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and it is monic, hence its content is $1$ i.e. $c(h(x))=1$. So that, $c(bh(x))=b×1=b$.
How to proceed further...? Or is there is alternative easier proof... please help

Comment: I would use long division of polynomials.  Even if $h$ does not divide $g$, still the Laurent series (convergent near $\infty$) of $g/h$ has integer coefficients.

Comment: This follows (after a little thought) from [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)).

Comment: @GregMartin sir, How? $g(x)$ is not primitive polynomial! Please elaborate.

Comment: Marcus, **Number Fields** proves this statement as follows; Let $m, n$ be minimal positive integers such that $mg(x) , nq(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Coefficients of $mg$ has no common factor other than $1$ (show this) and $nq$ also is. Now consider the image of $mnf =(mg)(nq)$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]$, which is an Euclidean domain (so it is integral domain), where $p$ is a prime factor of $mn$. Since it is a contradiction, there is no such $p$, i.e. $mn=1$. See Lemma for the theorem 1 in Chapter 2 if you have an access for the book.

Comment: Your formula (*) has $h$ and $g$ the wrong way round.

Comment: @RobArthan sir thanks for notifying it. I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply

> **Lemma** If $f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $f$ monic, then there exists (unique) $q(x),r(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\deg r<\deg f$ such that $g(x)=f(x)q(x)+r(x)$.

> *Proof of Lemma*: Induct on $\deg g$ -- if $\deg g<\deg f$ there is nothing to prove, otherwise $g(x)-f(x)\cdot LC(g)x^{\deg g-\deg f}$ has smaller degree, where $LC(g)$ is the leading coefficient of $g$ (i.e. coefficient of $x^{\deg g}$).  QED.

Comment: Sorry sir, I didn't get the proof of lemma. Further isn't there is any easier direct proof using definitions.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi while calling people "sir" is obviously intended to be polite, please remember that not all users of this site are male.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi It is as direct a proof as it can be --- just definition of divisibility in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ showing that division algorithm works in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as long as divisor is monic.

Comment: In lemma, we can also replace $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by $R[x]$ where $R$ is commutative ring with unity.

Comment: Yes we can, same proof.